# Dynamic require not supported in React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, webassembly

I have just tried to use wasm bindings in a react-native project. But the wasm bindings require access to node modules like `fs` so I used [rn-nodeify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-nodeify) as a work-around to get the React Native representation of `fs` and to be able to use `require`. That worked fine but I think that the wasm bindings are incompatible with react native, because I get the error `Dynamic require defined at line 10; not supported by Metro`. The error is talking about the line below:

```js
//line 10
const { TextDecoder, TextEncoder, inspect } = require(String.raw`util`);
```

The bindings I'm using are from this package [@iota/identity-wasm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@iota/identity-wasm)

### Steps to reproduce

If you want to reproduce this issue I have created a sample [RN Project](https://github.com/JonasHiltl/DigitalIdentityNodeified) that throws the error by startup.

```
git clone https://github.com/JonasHiltl/DigitalIdentityNodeified.git
cd ./DigitalIdentityNodeified
npm install
npx react-native start
npx react-native run-android
```

I'm interested to know what exactly a dynamic require is and if it's possible to replace the dynamic require with a normal one.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you cannot use require dynamicly in react-native :/

You will have to make a require for every single thing you will need.

Check out this for example:
[Dynamic require not supported in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68872230/dynamic-require-not-supported-in-react-native)